# How Action works in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, functional-programming

If I understand it correctly

```
    object Application extends Controller {
    def page1 = Action { Ok("Hello") } 
    }
```

can be written as

```
    object Application extends Controller {
    val f : Result = { Ok("Hello") }
    def page1 = Action( f )
    // i.e. Action.apply( f )
    }
```

The [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action) says An action is essentially a (Request[A] => Result) function that handles a request and generates a result to be sent to the client.

Since Action is essentially a function we can apply a function f to Action, i.e, Action.apply(f). Hope I'm correct up to this point.

Now for the following piece of code,

```
    def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Async {
      val cursor = collection.find(
        BSONDocument(), BSONDocument()).cursor[Patient] 
        val futureList = cursor.toList 
        futureList.map { patients => Ok(Json.toJson(patients)) } 
      }
    }
```

If I were to write

```
    def index = Action(f)
```

I want to be able to write a function f. My pseudocode is

```
    val f: Result = 
      //a function that takes Request[A] and returns Result
      {
        (request :Request[A]) => 
            Async {
              val cursor = collection.find(
                BSONDocument(), BSONDocument()).cursor[Patient] 
              val futureList = cursor.toList 
              futureList.map { patients => Ok(Json.toJson(patients)) } 
            }
      }
```

And I'm still struggling to get this working. Any help in writing the function would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the type of f as `Result` when it is really `Request[_] => Result`.

A correct version of f would be the following:

```
val f: Request[_] => Result = request =>
   Async {
      val cursor = collection.find(
         BSONDocument(), BSONDocument()).cursor[Patient] 
      val futureList = cursor.toList 
      Ok(Json.toJson(futureList ))
  }
}
```

Note that `Request[_]` cannot have a generic type parameter. To have Request be generic, f would have to be a def rather than a val.

Also, if `futureList` is a list then map will produce a list of `Result` rather than a single `Result`. I made corrections assuming you wanted a JSON list of all patients in the cursor.

Comment: Not the part of the original question, but can you also explain what's the use of implicit keyword in front of request? Thanks.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with implicits, I recommend http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html. In this case, marking the request as implicit causes it to be automatically applied to any function calls in the action that take an implicit request parameter. This is useful because in web application it is often necessary have access to the request outside of the controller (if there is a user ID on the request, for instance). So, by marking request as implicit and any of the functions that need a request as implicit, the request information is always automatically available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I used

```
    val f: Request[_] => Result = 
      //a function that takes Request[A] and returns Result
      {
         (request : Request[_]) => 
            Async {
              val cursor = collection.find(
                BSONDocument(), BSONDocument()).cursor[Patient] 
              val futureList = cursor.toList 
              futureList.map { patients => Ok(Json.toJson(patients)) } 
            }
      }
```

Hope this is the correct way of writing f that takes a Request[_] and returns a Result.